# 3D vertices $\rightarrow$ 2D polygon $\rightarrow$ 3d transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

This may be a little strange.

I have an array of 3D vertices, which represent a 3D face (n-gon). I first need to describe the face in 2D.  I can then apply these transforms on it.

- X, Y, and Z rotation
- X, Y, and Z positions

I'm looking for some pointers on what topics I should read up on do understand how to implement this in code.

Phrases I can type into Google, algorithms, and explanations are all appreciated.

---

So far I've come up with taking three points, $p,q,s$ where $q$ is connected to $p$ and $s$, and doing the following

$\vec{a} = q - p$
$\vec{b} = q - s$
$c = b \times \vec{{(0, 0, 0)}}$

To my understanding, that means that $c$ will hold the normal of $a$ and $b$.  Is this correct?

For example, the points $p,q,s$ are $[-1,0,-1];[-1,2,-1];[1,2,1]$, which results in $c$ being $[-4,0,4]$.

How do I take the normal vector and use it to move points from that plane to the XY plane?

Comment: The keywords here is probably "matrices". For example, for rotation there are "rotation matrices" that you can look up. In general if you know the positions of each vertex in 2D, and know where they map to in 3D space, then that will determine a transformation which can be represented as a matrix (which you can compute).

Comment: Is there a term for taking 3D coordinates that could be rotated to all have the same position on one axis, and performing that rotation?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you could probably find the equation of the plane that the polygon lies in and then find the matrix which maps that to, say, the xy-plane (where z=0 is the coordinate in common)

Comment: Do I want the surface normal, and then find the rotation between that and (0, 0, 0), and then apply that to the vertices?

Comment: I updated my question with what I could find.  I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: If you meant $c = b \times a$ then I think that looks fine (note that $-c$ is also normal to the plane). The xy-plane has normal vector $(0, 0, 1)$, so you need a rotational matrix which takes $c$ (or $-c$) to $(0, 0, 1)$.

I'm not too sure how to do that from the top of my head, by dot products and projections might help (you could probably do each x, y, z rotation one at a time)